# Lexical Analyser using C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I have done the program as reading a string and then converted to a file input. For a single line, it is getting output. I also want to display character,integer and floating point constants and symbols in the output.
For a multiline or for a c program as input, the arrays which are printed in the last just mix up each other and some another input is generated. Anyone have idea how this happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define KEYWORDS 32
#define OPERATORS 25
#define DEBUG_MODE 1

typedef enum {FALSE,TRUE} boolean;

char *trimString(char *str)
{
  char *end;

  // Trim leading space
  while(isspace((unsigned char)*str)) str++;

  if(*str == 0)  // All spaces?
    return str;

  // Trim trailing space
  end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
  while(end > str && isspace((unsigned char)*end)) end--;

  // Write new null terminator
  *(end+1) = 0;

  return str;
}

int main()
{
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f(){};""";
    char str[80],filename[40],*token,*keyword[30],*identifier[30],*operator[30],*literal[30],tmp[80];
    int state=0,i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,m=0,c,ch=0,isKeyword=0,isOperator=0;
    boolean isComment=FALSE;

    char* key[] = {"auto","break", "case", "char", "const", "continue", "default", "do", "double", "else", "enum", "extern", "float", "for", "goto", "if", "int", "long","register", "return", "short","signed", "sizeof", "static","struct", "switch","typedef","union", "unsigned", "void","volatile", "while"};

    char* operators[] = {"+", "-", "/", "*", "%", "=", "+=", "++", "--", "-=", "*=", "/=", "%=", "==", ">", "<", "!=", ">=", "<=", "&&", "||", "!", "<<", ">>", "sizeof"};

    printf("Enter the filename: ");
    gets(filename);

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError opening file with filename : \'%s\'!!\n\n",filename);
        exit(0);
    }
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), file))
    {   
        //Skip=FALSE;
        str[sizeof(str)-1]='\0';
        if((str[0]=='#') || (str[0]=='\n')) //remove preprocessor directives and blank lines
            goto gotoNextLine;

        if(str[0]=='/')
        {
            if(str[1]=='/')
                goto gotoNextLine;
            else if(str[1]=='*')
            {
                isComment=TRUE;
                goto gotoNextLine;
            }
        }


        if(DEBUG_MODE)      
            printf("\n\n**isComment=%d**\n\n",isComment);

        if(isComment)       // skip block comments
        {   
            c=0;
            while(str[c]!='\0')
            {
                if(str[c]=='*')
                {
                    if(str[c+1]=='/')
                    {
                        isComment=FALSE;
                        for (i=c+2; str[i]!='\0'; i++) 
                            tmp[ch++] = str[i];
                        strcpy(str,tmp);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(DEBUG_MODE)
                    printf("\n\n**The comment loop**\n\n");
                c++;
            }
        }

        if(!isComment)
        {
            for (token = strtok(str, delimit); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, delimit)) 
            {   
                isKeyword=0;
                isOperator=0;

                if(DEBUG_MODE)      
                    printf("\n\n**token=%s**\n\n",token);

                for (i=0;i<OPERATORS;i++)
                {
                    if(!strcmp(trimString(token),operators[i]))
                    {
                        isOperator=1;
                        operator[l++]=token;
                        break;//goto nextToken;
                    }
                }

                if(DEBUG_MODE)      
                    printf("\n\n**isOperator=%d**\n\n",isOperator);

                if(!isOperator)
                {
                    for (i=0;i<KEYWORDS;i++)
                    {
                        if(!strcasecmp(trimString(token),key[i]))
                        {
                            isKeyword=1;
                            keyword[j++]=token;
                            break;//goto nextToken;
                        }
                    }
                }


                if(DEBUG_MODE)      
                    printf("\n\n**isKeyword=%d**\n\n",isKeyword);


                if(!isKeyword && !isOperator)           
                {
                    i=ch=state=0;
                    if(token[0]=='"')
                    {
                        for (i=1; str[i]!='"'; i++) 
                            tmp[ch++] = token[i];
                        strcpy(token,tmp);
                        literal[m++]=token;
                        goto nextToken;
                    }
                    while(token[i]!='\0')
                    {
                        if((token[0]=='#') || (token[0]=='\n'))
                            goto nextToken;
                        switch(state)
                        {
                            case 0: if(isalpha(token[i]) || token[i]=='_')
                                {
                                    state=1;
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                    state=2;
                                break;
                            case 1: if(isalnum(token[i]) || token[i]=='_')  
                                {
                                    state=1;
                                    i++;
                                }
                                else
                                    state=2;
                                break;
                            case 2: goto nextToken;
                        }

                    }

                    if(state==1)
                    {
                        identifier[k++]=token;
                        if(DEBUG_MODE)      
                            printf("\n\n**Identifier_True=%s**\n\n",token);

                    }
                }

                nextToken: ;
            }
        }
        gotoNextLine: ;
    }

    if(DEBUG_MODE)      
        printf("\n\n**Keywords_Count=%d**\n\n",j);

    if(j)
    {
        printf("\nKeywords: \n");
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            printf("%s",keyword[i]);
            if((i+1)<j)
                printf(", ");   
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(DEBUG_MODE)      
        printf("\n\n**Operators_Count=%d**\n\n",l);

    if(l)
    {
        printf("\nOperators: \n");
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            printf("%s",operator[i]);
            if((i+1)<l)
                printf(", ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(DEBUG_MODE)      
        printf("\n\n**Identifiers_Count=%d**\n\n",k);

    if(k)
    {
        printf("\nIdentifiers: \n");
        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            printf("%s",identifier[i]);
            if((i+1)<k)
                printf(", ");   
        }
    }


    printf("\n");
    fclose(file);

}
```

Comment: Note: `strspn()` and `strcspn()` are handy functions. (and `strtok()` is a disaster waiting to happen;-) And: IMHO there is too much state floating around in this lexer.

Comment: Did you look into "Recursive descent parser" (here for example  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)?

Comment: @wildplasser too much state?

Comment: Please note that, since C99, including `<stdbool.h>` you can use `true` and `false`.

Comment: Also note that with `" \t\r\n\v\f(){};"""` the preprocessor is adding an empty literal string to `" \t\r\n\v\f(){};"`. You probably wanted something like `char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f(){};\"\'";`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the arrays which are printed in the last just mix up each other and some another input is generated". It would make it easier to assist you if you showed the input you are putting in, the output you are getting and the output you are expecting.